# Are C++ function declarations optional?

Tags: c++

I just noticed something when creating functions. In the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b = 20)
{
    int r;
    r = a + b;
    return (r);
}

int main()
{
    int result;
    result = add(20);
    cout<<result;

    return 0;
}
```

it will work because the function being called is on top of the caller, but if I put the function `add()` below the calling function in `main()` it won't work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int result;
    result = add(20);
    cout<<result;

    return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b = 20)
{
    int r;
    r = a + b;
    return (r);
}
```

and the compiler will tell me that the identifier `add()` cannot be found. 
so why do we declare functions anyway? like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int a, int b = 20);

int main()
{
    int result;
    result = add(20);
    cout<<result;

    return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b)
{
    int r;
    r = a + b;
    return (r);
}
```

Comment: A definition is an implicit declaration. And a declaration must come ahead of the use.

Comment: @YvesDaoust - That's an answer. It belongs down bellow in the answer section, where it may be voted upon.

Comment: It's like that  starting from Kernighan and Ritchie. It was designed this way to make writing one-pass compiler a bit easier ;-)

Comment: @StoryTeller: you are right. When my answers are so terse, I tend to leave them as comments if I am too lazy to explain more.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : Please don't.  Please answer the question in the answers section.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so basically a definition is like a person, cannot be used if it hasn't been born yet,  or declared...

Comment: @JohnSmith: when the compiler meets an identifier for the first time, it cannot guess what it is if more details haven't been given. In old C, there were default assumptions allowing the compiler to supply the missing declarations. This was bad practice and is not possible in C++.

Answer (score 9):

A definition is implicitly a declaration. And a declaration must come ahead of the use.

Comment: Actually, a definition is a type of declaration.  But not all declarations are definitions.

Answer (score 7):

All functions need to be declared before they are used.

You can do that by either (1) writing a declaration, or (2) writing a definition.

Relying solely on (2) can be tempting but then you are bound to order your program in a particular way, and is occasionally impossible. For example, the following will not compile unless the comment is removed.

```
   //void bar(int);

    void foo(int n)
    {
        if (!n){
            bar(n);
        }
    }

    void bar(int n)
        if (n){
            foo(n);
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        foo(1);
    }
```

Comment: @JohnSmith: That's pretty much it, yes. And `foo` needs to be below `bar`, and `bar` also needs to be below `foo`. And that's a problem.

Comment: Functions all the way down!

Comment: @StoryTeller: Interspersed with the occasional turtle.

Comment: Of course. A staple of the new design principle I intend to champion: "Turtle oriented programming".

Comment: @StoryTeller: You could base it on this delight from the 1990s: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtle_graphics

Answer (score 0):

**No**.

If the function definition appears before the function call, then prototype is not mandatory. Otherwise function prototype is necessary to let compiler know how to respond to a function when it is called.

Answer (score 0):

A function declaration tells the compiler about a function's name, return type, and parameters. A function definition provides the actual body of the function.

**if the function definition appears after the function call then prototype is mandatory. because it tells the compiler to how to respond the function when it is called.**

check the following example.

```
/* C++ Function Prototype and C++ Function Definition */

#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int, int);         // function prototype

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a, b;
    cout<<"Enter any two number: ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"\nSummation = "<<add(a, b);
    getch();
}

int add(int x, int y)     // function definition
{
    int res;
    res = x + y;
    return res;
}
```

**and if the function definition is made before the function call then it is not mandatory to declare function prototype.**

consider example.

```
/* C++ Function Prototype and C++ Function Definition */

#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int add(int x, int y)     // function definition
{
    int res;
    res = x + y;
    return res;
}

void main()
{
    clrscr();
    int a, b;
    cout<<"Enter any two number: ";
    cin>>a>>b;
    cout<<"\nSummation = "<<add(a, b);
    getch();
}
```